# Python: wait for a key press or until timeout

Tags: python

I have a long-running Python script inside a terminal session (the host machine is a FreeBSD box) that performs a task every 9 minutes. Now, I'd like to be able to interrupt that sleep call at any moment so that it performs the task right away.

How can I do that? Catching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not an option as I need it to stop the program (rather than merely interrupting the sleep). Anything else that I can do with a terminal window and a keyboard is fine.

Comment: "Catching Ctrl+C is not an option as I need it to stop the program." What?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sometimes I need to stop the program, and the simplest way to do it is to press Ctrl+C. Therefore, I don't want to interrupt the `sleep` by catching the `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Do you need to be able to kill the program by hitting Ctrl+C just once?  You could catch it the first time and kill it the second.  What about catching another signal?

Comment: Can't you just use Ctrl-\ for that?

Comment: @Thomas, I suppose I could catch another signal. I'm not sure how to do it from Python, but if you feel confident posting an answer that implies `SIGALRM` and interrupting a `raw_input` or something along these lines, that could be it. Double Ctrl+C, though, would have its own share of problems that I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I never heard about that key combination. I looked it up, and I suppose it could work if there was either a pipe or a backslash key on my keyboard. It isn't the case, though (I do these characters with [alt]+[+] and [alt]+[ù], respectivey, and ctrl+either one does nothing in a terminal window).

Comment: Use `stty` to bind `SIGQUIT` to a different combination then.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, a sigquit causes a core dump. I suppose I could also somehow disable core dumps for the session, but that's growing into a lot of working around for something I hoped to do from the script.

Comment: By default it dumps core. You could just point it to a different handler instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Thomas's suggestion, I came up with this function:

```
import signal

def input_or_timeout(timeout):
    def nothing(sig, frame): pass
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, nothing)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        raw_input()
        signal.alarm(0)
    except (IOError, EOFError): pass
```

It waits for input for at most `timeout` seconds.

<strike>Under Windows, I suppose you could replace `raw_input()` with `getch()` from `msvcrt`.</strike>

Comment: Under Windows you can't use this code at all because it doesn't support SIGALRM.